# Yii criteria - modify to include OR Condition

Tags: mysql, yii, yii-components

I have the following line of code that does a simple query

```
if ($this->fulfilled)
   $criteria->addCondition('fulfilled ' . (($this->fulfilled == 1) ? "IS NOT NULL" : "IS NULL"));
```

How can modify this to do a query that contains an OR command to basically run this query using the framework rather than raw SQL

```
if ($this->fulfilled)
AND (fulfilled is null OR fulfilled = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that

```
 $criteriaOr = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteriaOr->addCondition('fulfilled IS NULL', 'OR');
    $criteriaOr->addCondition('fulfilled = 0', 'OR');
```

Then `if($this->fulfielled) {$criteria->mergeWith($criteriaOr);}`